# How to break a loop running outside a java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, exception

I'm trying to implement multi threading inside a for loop so I can run the tasks in async mode parallelly. Suppose if I want to break the loop how do I do it?

```
for (int batchId = 0; batchId <= totalBatches && totalChangesetRows != 0; batchId++) {
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
try {
//Carrying out approval process
} catch (Exception e) {
//under certain circumstances need to break the for loop
break;
} },executorService);
```

But I get errors as break is outside the for loop.

Comment: It runs asynchronously. That means that code isn't required to run at the point where the for loop is executing. You can't break out of a loop that happened at a different time.

Comment: If so can I implement a logic outside the thread call to check if an exception was thrown and stop the loop. Sorry I'm just starting out on programming.